# Separating integers substrings from those with alphabetical letters

Tags: python, python-3.x, strings

The goal of my code is given a string, to separate the integer substrings from those containing solely alphabetical letters, with the individual substrings in a list.

For example:

- Input: `1h15min`
- Output: `["1", "h", "15", "min"]`

Here is the code:

```
def separate_text(input_text):
    if not input_text:
        return None
    character_list = []
    current_substring = ""
    string_type = ""
    for character in input_text:
        if character in "0123456789":
            if string_type in ("Int", ""):
                current_substring += character
                if string_type == "":
                    string_type = "Int"
            else:
                character_list.append(current_substring)
                string_type = "Int"
                current_substring = character
        elif character not in "0123456789":
            if string_type in ("Str", ""):
                current_substring += character
                if string_type == "":
                    string_type = "Str"
            else:
                character_list.append(current_substring)
                string_type = "Str"
                current_substring = character
    character_list.append(current_substring)
    return character_list
```

The function functions as follows:

- Take an input string (if empty, return `None`)
- Begin looping through the string, character by character
- If the character is an integer

  - If `string_type` is `Int` or `""`, append the character to `current_substring` and change `string_type` if needed
  - If `string_type` is `Str`, append the substring to the `character_list`, reassign `current_substring` to whatever the character is, and change the `string_type` to `"Int"`.
- If the character is an string

  - If `string_type` is `Str` or `""`, append the character to `current_substring` and change `string_type` if needed
  - If `string_type` is `Int`, append the substring to the `character_list`, reassign `current_substring` to whatever the character is, and change the `string_type` to `"Str"`.
- End of the whole string? Append `current_substring` to the list and return the `character_list`.

My questions here are:

- Is there any way to make the program for Pythonic?
- Can I possible shorten my code? The two main `if` statements in the `for` loop have nearly identical code.

Note that I do not count floats so `1.15min` returns `['1', '.', '15', 'min']`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `elif` in

> ```
>    if character in "0123456789":
>         // ...
>     elif character not in "0123456789":
>         // ...
> ```

can be replaced by an `else`.

> ```
> if string_type in ("Int", ""):
>     current_substring += character
>     if string_type == "":
>         string_type = "Int"
> else:
>     character_list.append(current_substring)
>     string_type = "Int"
>     current_substring = character
> ```

can be simplified to

```
if character in "0123456789":
    if string_type == "Str":
        character_list.append(current_substring)
        current_substring = ""
    string_type = "Int"
    current_substring += character
```

and similarly for the non-digits case. However, using strings
(`""`, `"Str"`, `"Int"`) for the current state is error-prone. 
An enumeration would be an alternative, or in this case simply a boolean:

```
in_digits = None
for character in input_text:
    if character in "0123456789":
        if in_digits is False:
            character_list.append(current_substring)
            current_substring = ""
        in_digits = True
        current_substring += character
    else:
    // ...
```

And now the two cases can be combined into one:

```
in_digits = None
for character in input_text:
    is_digit = character in "0123456789"
    if in_digits == (not is_digit):
        character_list.append(current_substring)
        current_substring = ""
    in_digits = is_digit
    current_substring += character
```

More remarks:

> ```
> if not input_text:
>     return None
> ```

When called with an empty string, I would expect the function to return
an empty array, not `None`.

> ```
> character_list = []
> ```

The variable name is slightly misleading, this is a list of *strings.*

Summarizing the suggestions so far, we have

```
def separate_text(input_text):
    string_list = []
    current_substring = ""
    in_digits = None
    for character in input_text:
        is_digit = character in "0123456789"
        if in_digits == (not is_digit):
            string_list.append(current_substring)
            current_substring = ""
        in_digits = is_digit
        current_substring += character
    string_list.append(current_substring)
    return string_list
```

Finally note that the same can be simply achieved by splitting the
string on a regular expression:

```
import re

def separate_text(input_text):
    return [item for item in re.split('(\d+)', input_text) if item]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your goal  can also easily be achieved using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), which groups an iterable using some function (here [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)):

```
from itertools import groupby

def separate_text(input_text):
    return ["".join(g) for _, g in groupby(input_text, key=str.isdigit)]
```

Whether you want to use the [one-line regex solution](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/192689/98493) by [@MartinR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/35991/martin-r) or this one-line `itertools` solution does not really matter (you should test if the runtime is different for your usual inputs, though) What matters is that both are way easier to read (and write).

---

You should also add a [`docstring`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) describing what the function does:

```
def separate_text(input_text):
    """Separate `input_text` into runs of digits and non-digits.

    Examples:
    >>> separate_text("1h15min")
    ['1', 'h', '15', 'min']

    >>> separate_text("1.15min")
    ['1', '.', '15', 'min']
    """
    ...
```

The usage examples I added have the advantage that you can use it to have automatic unittests using [`doctest`](https://pymotw.com/3/doctest/). Just run the file with the module loaded:

```
$ python -m doctest -v path/to/separate_text.py
Trying:
    separate_text("1h15min")
Expecting:
    ['1', 'h', '15', 'min']
ok
Trying:
    separate_text("1.15min")
Expecting:
    ['1', '.', '15', 'min']
ok
1 items had no tests:
    separate_text
1 items passed all tests:
   2 tests in separate_text.separate_text
2 tests in 2 items.
2 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
```